# Debugging SQL Server 2005 database with SQL Server 2008 R2 Debugger

Tags: sql-server, debugging

I am using **SQL Server 2008** R2 Management Studio for an old database that is **SQL Server 2005** based. I want to debug my T-SQL code but SQL Server is telling me:

> the transact-sql debugger does not support SQL Server 2005 or earlier
>   versions of SQL Server

What can I do for debugging that T-SQL code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right Management Studio 2008 doesn't support SQL Server 2005 T-SQL code debug.

But you can use Visual Studio. I hope, this article will help to you http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/27/debugging-stored-procedures-in-sql-server-2005